# Address list object with jquery

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I would like to address this list with jquery.

```
<ul> <li id="unique_id"> Some Stuff </li> </ul>
```

Can someone tell me how I do this. This doesn't work.

```
$('ul li #unique_id').blink();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('ul li#unique_id').blink();
```

The space after `li` says that it should look for a descendant with an `id` of `unique_id`; you want an `li` with an `id` of `unique_id`.

Usually, however, you *don't* want to be that specific. `id`s are meant to be unique throughout the entire page, and being less specific can even be more efficient:

```
$('#unique_id').blink();
```

Answer (score 0):

To target the LI element:

```
$('#unique_id').blink(); //it has a unique ID
```

to target the UL element:

```
$('#unique_id').closest('ul').blink(); //it still has an ID
```